# Talend get row affected by delete with tmysqlrow

Tags: count, row, talend

I have an issue with a Talend Job. I need to delete dome rows (the query will be given by a previous component). To simplify, I do this :

[image]

If I uncheck "Propagate query recordset", the job run perfectly.
But after checking (I use the same kind of component with MSSQL without issue), the job failed with the error message :

```
Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
```

And I specify "AllowMultiQueries" in additional parameters of component connexion.

Is it a way to get the number of rows deleted with a tmysqlrow ? I would like to prevent to use before a tmysqlinput, then get the count(*), and then delete.

Comment: Why are you using `tMysql*` for MSSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a `tMysqlRow` to handle the delete, followed by a `tMysqlInput` to return the number of deleted rows :

[image]

The `DELETE` and `SELECT` must be issued using the same connection, so a `tMysqlConnection` is necessary and a `tMysqlCommit` at the end (tMysqlCommit is necessary to commit the changes, unless you're using autocommit on the connection, which you shouldn't by the way)

**Alternative solution**

Here's an alternative solution, in which I send a list of `ID`s (defined in `tFixedFlowInput`, but could very well be read from file..etc) to be deleted to a `tMysqlOutput` (action on data set to Delete), and set the id column as key in the component schema:

[image]

Then you can simply use the `tMysqlOutput_NB_LINE_DELETED` global variable, to get the number of deleted rows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I thought, but I wanted to know if there was a easer way to achieve that.
Regards

Comment: That's weird, it worked for me.. I used a tMysqlConnection before and a tMysqlCommit at the end, could you try with that ?

Comment: yes it works now. I try too with a input (select count) before. works too.
Thanks !

Comment: Cool. So it was the tMysqlConnection that made it work ? (so I can update my answer). Using an input (select count) is not appropriate in my opinion, as the row count might change between the moment you count them, and the actual deletion.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and added a screenshot for better readability